# Why aren't test dependencies compiledin Maven?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, morphia

I’m trying to use Morphia (MongoDB) in a Tomcat application. But I’m getting this Error:

[image: Error message: SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found. SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details. Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson at dev.morphia.Morphia.createDatastore(Morphia.java:90)]

The given [link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders) confirms that the JAR files are missing.

In the pom.xml file Morphia is added with compile as scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.morphia.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

All dependencies are added as library and are useable inside Eclipse.

[image: Maven Libraries]

But only Morphia itself is being compiled.

With a look at [MVNrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.morphia/morphia/1.3.2) I suspected that only "Compile Dependencies" and not "Test Dependencies" are being compiled.

But adding SLF4J API additionally to pom.xml didn't change anything.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a dependency "is being compiled"? Your dependencies (except provided and test dependencies)  are packed into your WAR.

Comment: you are missing slf4j providers. why do you think adding SLF4J api would help? an api is not a provider.

Comment: also, to the subject: test dependencies are meant to be only used in (unit) test phase, not when you run the application. that's why they are not packaged.

Comment: @JFabianMeier The problem is, that the "SLF4J API" dependency isn't packed into the WAR file even though it is scoped as compile.

Comment: Did you have a look at `mvn dependency:list`? Maybe the scope is overridden somewhere. Furthermore, it would be helpful to see the whole POM.

Answer (score 0):

Like @eis and the given [link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders) said I had to add a provider, not only the API.

But also the Versions were incompatible. If anyone else has this problem use this versions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.morphia.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```